How to setup the database in base_controler to make it globally avivable?
i setup my first Codeigniter4 project. I failed on adding the database-connection to the basecontroller to make the db-connection avivable in all controllers/models/helpers etc. to avoid setup it again and again in every file.
So like the docu i think i have to do it with the basecontroller like this
...
public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        //Create global instance for DB-Connections
        //$globalDB = db_connect('globalDB');
        //$this->globalDB = \Config\Database::connect('globalDB'); //db_connect('globalDB');
    ...
    }

if i try to work with it inside a modell, it failed
return $globalDB->query('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1;')->getResultArray();
//return $this->globalDB->query('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1;')->getResultArray();

i get error messages like this "Undefined variable $globalDB"
So what am i doing wrong, maybe i missundestood something?
